# Bash script error on boot

Tags: bash, shell-script, init-script

I have to tune my laptop's keyboard behaviour by lowering its brightness timeout, so I placed a one-line command in a script file, executed at boot. Here is it:

```
$ cat /usr/local/bin/boot-script.sh

#!/bin/bash

echo "10s" | sudo tee /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell\:\:kbd_backlight/stop_timeout
```

Unfortunately, I get an error on boot saying:

```
machi boot-script.sh[362]: tee: '/sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/stop_timeout': No such file or directory
machi boot-script.sh[362]: 10s
```

Despite, the file exists:

```
$ cat /sys/devices/platform/dell-laptop/leds/dell::kbd_backlight/stop_timeout
10s
```

Why do I get this error?
How can I fix it?

Thanks

Comment: That file exists **when** you ls from your shell. It might not already exist at the time boot-script.sh is launched. I mean the precise directory tree could be populated after in the init process.

Comment: To ensure invoke at correct time, others have found success by creating a systemd unit, which invokes *after* graphic display starts.  https://gist.github.com/mhitza/c454f5d8a30edb122f56bc67ffb386be

Comment: @MC68020 how can I check it?

Comment: Well… you already did, didn't you ? Then being said that I would consider that sort of setting better to be left to the user than to be set at system init time, if you disagree then, if under the systemd init system, follow the link suggested by @steve, if using openrc init system then tell, I will elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, the **only way** I found to fix the issue is to force the loading of the related kernel module (`dell_laptop` in my case) early in the boot process.

I am on Arch Linux, and I have achieved it by adding ***dell_laptop*** in the ***MODULES=()*** array in `/etc/mkinitcpio.conf`.

---

Furthermore:

1. as @MC68020 stated, the implicated magic file is not yet present when the script is executed
2. why does trick posted by @steve does not work? is there somewhere any other problem?
3. is it the best way to overcome this issue?